# Google map acting weird

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the most basic google map embeded in my website and this is what I ended up with when I included google maps api in the  and wrote this piece of code in the external script which I include in the  after the google maps api:

[image]

I can't do anything with it (zoom in or out, move the view around with the mouse..) except for switching between map and satellite. When I paste the exact same code in the w3schools "Try it yourself" area, everything works fine.

JavaScript:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.1676, 14.7589),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map=new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:myCenter,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Don't know if it has to do anything with my css settings but I can't paste the code here cause it's quite large.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Whats your html looking like?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nttaLvqs/ 

This is the basic layout of my page. From <section> up it's jut more section tags with it's own divs and I don't think it doesn't matter.
However #contact_left_side and #contact_right_side are set to float:left and #content_wrapper is set to overflow: hidden to stay wrapped around them. Maybe that's causing all the trouble

Comment: The map/satellite buttons looks like a css issue. You'll likely need to go through your styles and isolate the rule that's causing this, ie. make it more specific to whatever it is in your layout that it should be styling. As for not being able to drag/zoom, check your console for a JS error.

Comment: Thanks, too bad you didn't make a new answer instead of commenting my    post cause you got it right. The problem with zooming was that I didn't even initialize myCenter variable and it returned error in console. Don't know how I missed to reconfigure that part. And the problem with the looks of the satellite and map bars was that I set the parent divs height to 100% for some reason even if it wasn't necessary. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to know the problem was that the parent div of the map was set to height: 100% and that is what caused that glitch to happen.